# Is taking AWS Machine Learning Specialty Certification worth it?

Tags: machine-learning

I am currently a penultimate university student studying computer science. I am interested in Data Science and have worked on some data science-related projects and courses. I want to take this certification because I got a 50% discount and want to improve my career prospect as a data scientist. Is it worth to take the certification?